# Trying to Download boto using pip for python

Tags: python, pip, boto

I installed pip using `sudo easy_install pip` so that i could donload boto for python.  I then did `pip install -U boto` and go this error

```
    Installing collected packages: boto
    Cleaning up...
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 283, in run
        requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1435, in install
        requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 671, in install
        self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 901, in move_wheel_files
        pycompile=self.pycompile,
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 215, in move_wheel_files
        clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 205, in clobber
        os.makedirs(destdir)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
        mkdir(name, mode)
    OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto'

    Storing debug log for failure in /Users/DRizzuto/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

so then I tried doing `easy_install boto` and go this error

```
The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-2024.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.
```

I do not know how to install boto now.  Can someone please explain how I can either get around or get rid of these errors?

Comment: Try `sudo pip install -U boto`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run the pip command as root. (Or equivalent i.e. sudo)

Example based on Mac

```
sudo pip install -U boto
```

Comment: can you expand on that, i do not know what that means

Comment: What OS are you on? Ubuntu? Mac?

Comment: I am on a mac using terminal

Comment: Yep then you need to use sudo, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

By default pip attempts to install packages in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`, as you can see in the error message. This directory belongs to the "root" user and ordinary accounts do not have access to install things there.

`sudo` runs a command as root, so in this case you can just enter

```
sudo pip install -U boto
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use `sudo` in case of **boto**.

Using `sudo` (installing module to global path) might be a good solution for modules that truly belong to the global path (meaning we are sure we'll be using these throughout the system - typically tools like `ansible`, `virtualenv`, maybe `fabric` - but that's arguable).

Most other dependencies (including `boto`) should be always defined in `requirements.txt` that should be packed along with the app. Each app may (and will) have different dependencies, different modules of different versions and you **don't want to cause any clash/mess in the global path**.

With `virtualenv` though, you can create a virtual environment and keep only the most important stuff (like the actual `virtualenv` module) in the global environment and all project-related dependencies in the "virtual" environment.

Read more about `virtualenv`: http://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/

There might be more other solutions than just `virtualenv` for isolating the environment,
but **the point is that you should be isolating it**.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this blog. You are facing problem with permission

http://nitheeshp.blogspot.in/2014/05/configuring-and-installing-boto-on.html